# How do I fix postgres'> when I try to create a new role in my aws rds

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

when I try to run the command create role new_user with passowed 'passowrd' login; it just gives me postgres'> on a new line. I am logged in as a superuser in aws postgres rds. what does this mean and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

That means that your typing on the command line is as sloppy as your typing in Stackoverflow, and you didn't close the single quotes properly. Now `psql` is waiting for you to continue the string input.

Reset the query buffer by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and start again, taking care that you balance the quotes.

Perhaps the password contains a single quote, which you would have to escape by doubling it.

Let me remark that setting a password like this is unsafe: the password is visible on your screen, will end up in your history file, is sent over the line in clear text and may end up in the PostgreSQL log. Use `\password` to set the password, then you also don't have to worry about escaping single quotes.